# How to implement RecyclerView of android for very fast updating (Realtime app)?

Tags: android

I've developed an application to monitor the performance of electricity meters, communicate via MQTT, and display them with RecyclerView.
I've encountered a problem where multiple meters are updating at the same time. In Sometimes, RecyclerView will misbehave, e.g. 3. In Sometimes, RecyclerView takes the value from the 2rd meter and displays the value on the 1st.

**This is an example of a problem.**

[image]

**This is an example program.**

```
    private void updateDeviceStatus(final int index, final String mess) {
        Device device = devices.get(index);
        String []d = mess.split(",");
        if (d.length>=device.model.log.size()){
            //Normal
            device.error = null;
            //Update log data
            for(int x=0; x<device.model.log.size(); x++){
                //Update
                LogData data = device.model.log.get(x);
                data.now = d[x];
                device.model.log.set(x, data);
            }
        }else {
            //Show Error
            device.error = "Error Log Data!";
        }
        devices.set(index, device);
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can solved the problem by using the LiveData library.

**1. Implement the LiveData library at build.gradle (app)**

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.6.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.1"
```

**2. Create a Model class**

```
public class DeviceLive {
  private Device device;
  private int index;

  public DeviceLive(int index, Device device) {
    this.device = device;
    this.index = index;
  }

  public void setDevice(Device device) {
    this.device = device;
  }

  public Device getDevice() {
    return device;
  }

  public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
  }

  public int getIndex() {
    return index;
  }
}
```

**3. Create a ViewModel class**

```
public class DeviceViewModel extends ViewModel {
  private MutableLiveData<DeviceLive> currentDevice;

  public MutableLiveData<DeviceLive> getCurrentDevice() {
    if (currentDevice == null) {
        currentDevice = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    return currentDevice;
  }
}
```

**4. Initial at onCreate() of MainActivity**

```
private ArrayList<Device> devices;
private DeviceAdapter adapter;
private DeviceViewModel viewModel;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //View
    RecyclerView rvStatus = findViewById(R.id.node_rv);

    //Devices
    devices = new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayoutManager rvManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    adapter = new DeviceAdapter(this, this, devices);
    rvStatus.setLayoutManager(rvManager);
    rvStatus.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Use 'LiveData' for solved the RecyclerView show miss data via MQTT received
    // https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata
    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DeviceViewModel.class);
    final Observer<DeviceLive> observer = new Observer<DeviceLive>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(DeviceLive live) {
            //Update list
            devices.set(live.getIndex(), live.getDevice());
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(live.getIndex());
        }
    };
    // Observe the LiveData, passing in this activity as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
    viewModel.getCurrentDevice().observe(this, observer);
  }

  ...
}
```

**5. Edits the updateDeviceStatus function**

```
private void updateDeviceStatus(final int index, final String mess) {
    Device device = devices.get(index);
    String []d = mess.split(",");
    if (d.length>=device.model.log.size()){
        //Normal
        device.error = null;
        //Update log data
        for(int x=0; x<device.model.log.size(); x++){
            //Update
            LogData data = device.model.log.get(x);
            data.now = d[x];
            device.model.log.set(x, data);
        }
    }else {
        //Show Error
        device.error = "Error Log Data!";
    }

    // Use 'LiveData' for solved the RecyclerView show miss data via MQTT received
    // Must use 'postValue()' replace 'setValue()' because it can update data from background thread
    // and it use the last data for updating.
    viewModel.getCurrentDevice().postValue(new DeviceLive(index, device));
}
```

*I tried using 'setValue()' instead of 'postValue()' and found that it had the same result as the problem I encountered above.

[More details about LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the problem from a lower point of view.

Facts we know about:

- A RecyclerView is just a view, capable of (together with an 'Adapter') displaying a series of Views ('ViewHolders'), delegating the final arrangement and placement to a 'LayoutManager'.
- The content of these *Views* may change at any time, and *someone* has to re-bind (in RecyclerView's terms) the 'ViewHolders' to the new content/data.
- A RecyclerView has the added benefit that will *recycle* (reuse) views to save CPU and processing, mostly because View Inflation and measurement is considered to be slow and expensive, so by reusing the views that are no longer visible instead of creating new ones, a RecyclerView can scroll faster and smoother.
- The RecyclerView has no idea where the data is coming from, and is not responsible for fetching it, updating it, or any of the sort. Its job is to merely display the views and coordinate with the other delegates (layout manager, adapter, viewholders) to do their job.

#### Suggestion

Use a `ListAdapter<T,K>`. That will force you to use a `DiffUtil`. This alone will help you separate your concerns about the data handling and ownership, as it will not require you to manipulate the data with the "rows" in your head, but rather as a list of `Things`. The Adapter will take care of telling the RecyclerView what changed and what not, so you wouldn't need to use any of the `notify...` methods.

Separate your data gathering, from your data preparation, from the data you supply to your adapter/recyclerview.

I imagine you have something like this:

`Activity/Fragment` has a `RecyclerView/Adapter`.
`ViewModel` talks to your `DevicesManager` (Whoever reads the data from the actual devices and produces a `List<Device>`).

The view model either talks to this class directly or via an Interactor or via a UseCase it's just architecture nuances at this point. The fact is, someone produces a List of `Device`.

In this `Device` you have various values (I counted six but there may be more), think:

```
data class Device(var title: String, var currentA: String, var currentB: ...)
```

you get the idea, and any other info that you'll later need in the ViewHolder should be there.

Your `ViewModel` receives this data (maybe constantly if it's a socket/constant Flow or similar). Say for e.g. once per second.

What your `ViewModel` does is, either Transform/Modify the `List<Device>` into something different `List<DeviceModel>` that is in a different order or whatever *transformation* you need to perform, and emits a new State. You used LiveData, that's fine, a *better* alternative would be a `StateFlow` (but live data works too).

Your `Fragment` is observing this (as you correctly did) and now, when it receives this new `List<Device>` (or similar) *all it needs to do is* call `adapter.submitList(theNewList)`.

The DiffUtil will calculate for you what needs to be updated.

If you need an example on how to put a ListAdapter together, [this super simple repository](https://github.com/Gryzor/TheSimplestRV/tree/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/thesimplestrv) has you covered.

In there, the `DemoModel` is your `Device`. `DemoAdapter` is the Adapter. And the `DiffUtil` is `DiffCallback`.

The RecyclerView in the fragment is merely:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

From there, you have the pieces you need to re-architecture your RecyclerView to make it less aware of who/where is the data coming from. You're almost there.

My final piece of advice is: *do not mutate the list that you passed to the adapter*, make a *copy* first if you need to, otherwise, remember this is *Java* (or Kotlin) and things are references to objects, so if you change one object in a list that you passed to another method, chances are you're *modifying the same list*, this will confuse the Adapter/RecyclerView as things are changed *behind the scenes*.

Comment: Nice feature with ListAdapter where diff updates are done on a background thread.  However, I have to-date found it impossible to move items (up or down) in the Recyclerview list using ListAdapter.  Some on stackoverflow have commented how a deep copy of the entire list is the way to go, but then making a deep copy seems to defeat the benefits of ListAdapter's diff updates on a background thread.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: There are various approaches to dealing with this, depending how you move items. I'd say that sorting is a data issue (not a RV problem). Alas, due to how the ListAdapter (and DiffUtilCallback) are implemented, the simplest way would be a deep copy, and produce a new list. The benefit of the list adapter are just to calculate the animations and rendering/rebinding of the data. Unfortunately, (in part due to how Java/Kotlin pass by reference), if you "touch" the original collection, you're also touching the adapter's collection.

Comment: I'd say if you have a list of `T` where `T` is your Data object (say, the internal entity you use to model the data from your sensors), then have your viewModel call a class like `fun transform(source: T) -> K` where K is the data model you pass to your `adapter.submitList(List<K>)`. Every time you need to change something, you grab your list of `T`s, mutate it, sort it, change it, etc., then produce a new `List<K>` and call submit list. That should work. Yes it's "inefficient" to some degree, but use small data classes, let the language do its job.

Comment: Alternatively, grab your original `List<K>` and manually create copies of the modified items (list[0].copy(...)) but unless you have thousands of records, creating a new list every time in a background thread and submitting an entire new list is probably simpler, will waste less of your time and will likely work. Do you plan on doing continuous updates every second for e.g.?

Comment: I appreciate the replies.  I don't know Kotlin so I am limited to looking for a Java solution.  I've posted a question on how to move items and the code I've tried so far with no luck, here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76808289/3796660