# Android: how to copy a RecyclerView List for use by ListAdapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter

How do I copy the existing ListAdapter list so that it can be used to move items and then update the UI by comparing the new, copied list to the original list?

Perhaps the Android devs only thought of CRUD operations when they designed the source code for ListAdapter to be used for RecyclerView lists.  If so, they neglected to account for other vital recyclerView operations like filtering, sorting and moving list items.  The only thing that is changing for those operations is the sort order (sorting and moving items) or removing some items from the original list (for filtering) but that would now require a CustomAdapter? Also, the requirement to copy a list into memory, for a very large RecyclerView list so the ListAdapter "sees" a new list, seems to defeat the original purpose of the ListAdapter to provide efficiency gains on a background thread.

I embraced converting my existing project to ListAdapter with the thought that updates on a background thread would be very valuable for stability and UI efficiency.  I have CRUD ops working fine but now the daunting task is to figure out how to do those other filtering, sorting and moving list items.

I tried to move items in the RecyclerView list but drag-and-drop does not work.  Below are the different methods I've tried so far in various combinations.  In the meantime, I read every other ListAdapter question on stackoverflow...and unfortunately I know zero Kotlin so I am looking for a Java solution.  What am I missing here?

MainActivity approach #1:

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback1 = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
   (ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN),0) {

    int dragFrom = -1;
    int dragTo = -1;    

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

        int fromPos = viewHolder.getBindingAdapterPosition();
        int toPos = target.getBindingAdapterPosition();

        if (dragFrom == -1) {
            dragFrom = fromPos;
        }
        dragTo = toPos;

        cardsAdapter.moveItem(fromPos, toPos);                        
        return true;
    }  
};        
new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback1).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

MainActivity approach #2, for the onMove() method:

```
List newList = adapter.getCurrentList();
Quickcard quickcardItem = newList.get(fromPos);
newList.remove(fromPos);
newList.add(toPos, quickcardItem);
cardsAdapter.moveItem(fromPos, toPos);
cardsAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPos, toPos);
cardsAdapter.submitList(newList);
return true;
```

ListAdapter approach #1:

```
public class CardsAdapter extends ListAdapter<Quickcard, CardsAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    protected CardsAdapter(@NonNull LayoutInflater layoutInflater, DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Quickcard> diffCallback) {
        super(diffCallback);
        this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
    }

    ... // ViewHolder code 
     
    public void moveItem(int fromOldPos, int toNewPos) {

        // Copy the ListAdapter's existing list
        ArrayList<Quickcard> currList = new ArrayList<>(getCurrentList()); 
    
        if (fromOldPos == toNewPos) {
            return;
        }
        Collections.swap(currList, toNewPos, fromOldPos);
        notifyItemMoved(fromOldPos, toNewPos);
        submitList(currList);
    }     
}
```

ListAdapter approach #2, for the moveItem() method:

```
List<Quickcard> currList = getCurrentList();
List<Quickcard> copiedList = new ArrayList<>(currList);

if (fromOldPos == toNewPos) {
    return;
}
if (fromOldPos < toNewPos) { // the q. is being moved down the q.list
    for (int i = fromOldPos; i < toNewPos; i++) {
    Collections.swap(copiedList, i,i + 1);
    }
} else { // the q. is being moved up the q.list
    for (int i = fromOldPos; i > toNewPos; i--) {
        Collections.swap(copiedList, i,i - 1);
    }
}
notifyItemMoved(fromOldPos, toNewPos);
submitList(copiedList);
```

// after adding a copy constructor to the Model, I also tried this

// (see @Matt's answer stackoverflow #48575477),

ListAdapter approach #3, for the moveItem() method:

```
List<CustomObject> copyList = new ArrayList<>();
for(CustomObject obj : parentList) {
    copyList.add(new CustomObject(obj));
}
```

I also tried this approach, in the ViewModel:

```
// mTodos is the MutableLiveData<List> in the ViewModel
List<Todo> todos = mTodos.getValue();
ArrayList<Todo> clonedTodos = new ArrayList<Todo>(todos.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < todos.size(); i++){
        clonedTodos.add(new Todo(todos.get(i)));
    }        
    mTodos.postValue(clonedTodos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunaly the `ListAdapter` by itself has trouble with drag/swipe operations, but most of the nice features of the `submitList` method can be duplicated using `DiffUtil` methods in a regular adapter. You can handle filtering by filtering the list elsewhere (e.g. in the ViewModel) and the posting it with `submitList`. By doing this, you have access to the displayed list and can modify it easily for drag/swipe events, while still getting some of the benefits of the `ListAdapter` when posting new lists or re-ordered lists.

Here's an example of how to do that and get a working drag/swipe behavior with "ListAdapter-like" behavior for `submitList` that uses `DiffUtil` tools. You do lose the background thread for the diff callback. That could be added back in to `submitList` with a bit more difficulty (or you could use Kotlin and coroutines to add it more easily).

**The adapter**

Since the adapter has access to the displayed list, it can move items around in it, or remove them, when items are moved/swiped away. When a new list is posted with `submitList`, it uses the DiffUtil methods to compare the new list to the currently displayed list, updates the displayed list, and dispatches changes to the recycler view to be animated.

If you need to propagate order changes/swiping back to a ViewModel or other layer, pass an interface to the adapter and call it in `onItemMove` and `onItemDismiss` as appropriate to let the backend know that item position changed or items were removed. Such changes should not cause the backend to submit a new list to `submitList` since the displayed list is already updated.

```java
public class RecyclerViewAdapter 
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> 
    implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter 
{
    // Define a diff callback, similar to what is used in ListAdapter,
    // but with a couple other methods.
    private static class DiffCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback {
        DiffCallback(List<RecyclerViewData> old) {
            oldList = old;
        }

        @Override
        public int getOldListSize() {
            return oldList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getNewListSize() {
            return newList.size();
        }

        // Each entry in the example has a UUID, this compares only
        // the UUID, not the name or birthday, to determine if an 
        // item moved
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
            return oldList.get(oldItemPosition).isSameEntry(newList.get(newItemPosition));
        }

        // Compare the displayed data (name and birthday) to decide
        // if it should be redrawn/rebound
        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
            return oldList.get(oldItemPosition).isSameAs(newList.get(newItemPosition));
        }

        List<RecyclerViewData> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<RecyclerViewData> oldList;
    }

    // Basic ViewHolder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name;
        TextView birthday;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            birthday = itemView.findViewById(R.id.birthday);
        }
    }

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final ArrayList<RecyclerViewData> displayedList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final DiffCallback diffCallback = new DiffCallback(displayedList);

    public RecyclerViewAdapter (Context ctx) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }

    // Implement methods from ItemTouchHelperAdapter interface, to be called
    // from the ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback
    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder from, RecyclerView.ViewHolder to) {
        int fromP = from.getAdapterPosition();
        int toP = to.getAdapterPosition();

        if( fromP == toP ) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            Collections.swap(displayedList, fromP, toP);
            notifyItemMoved(fromP, toP);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position, int direction) {
        displayedList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    // Mimic the ListAdapter "submitList" method, but without the benefit
    // of a background thread. Could be added if needed, but adds complexity.
    public void submitList(List<RecyclerViewData> newList) {
        diffCallback.newList = newList;
        DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback);
        displayedList.clear();
        displayedList.addAll(newList);
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
    }

    // Basic RecyclerView stuff
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_row,parent,false);
        return new RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RecyclerViewData data = displayedList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(data.getName());
        holder.birthday.setText(data.getBirthday());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return displayedList.size();
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.profile_list);

    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    ItemTouchHelper ith = new ItemTouchHelper(new SimpleItemTouchHelper(adapter));
    ith.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    
    // this should come from a ViewModel, just here for simplicity
    ArrayList<RecyclerViewData> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(new RecyclerViewData("Bob", "Jan 12"));
    data.add(new RecyclerViewData("Frank", "Feb 12"));
    data.add(new RecyclerViewData("Herbert", "Mar 22"));
    data.add(new RecyclerViewData("Joe", "Apr 15"));
    data.add(new RecyclerViewData("Bob", "Jan 12"));
    
    // when the ViewModel gets data, or filters the list to show it in a new order,
    // it calls "submitList" and the adapter figures out what to show/move
    adapter.submitList(data);
}
```

**The item touch interface**

(not strictly necessary, but nice to decouple the adapter from the item touch helper)

```java
public interface ItemTouchHelperAdapter {
    boolean onItemMove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder from, RecyclerView.ViewHolder to);
    void onItemDismiss(int position, int direction);
}
```

**The item touch callback**

Simple callback that just calls `onItemMove` and `onItemDismiss` on the adapter.

```java
public class SimpleItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

    private final ItemTouchHelperAdapter adapter;
    SimpleItemTouchHelper(ItemTouchHelperAdapter adapter) {
        super(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return adapter.onItemMove(viewHolder, target);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        adapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), direction);
    }
}
```

**The data class**

```java
public class RecyclerViewData {
    private final String uuid;
    private final String name;
    private final String birthday;

    public RecyclerViewData(String name, String birthday) {
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.name = name;
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public boolean isSameEntry(RecyclerViewData other) {
        return this.uuid.equals(other.uuid);
    }

    public boolean isSameAs(RecyclerViewData other) {
        return this.name.equals(other.name) && 
               this.birthday.equals(other.birthday);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getBirthday () {
        return birthday;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post and example.  Still trying to do with ListAdapter so that I don't lose the diff updates on the background thread.

Comment: @AJW Unfortunately I think ListAdapter is fundamentally incompatible with the move/swipe list editing operations. Best I've come up with is to re-post the re-ordered list, but the animations happen twice and it looks terrible. It's probably worth profiling the actual cost of the diff operation to see how expensive it is.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with it, but I think I had swipe-to-remove working fine with ListAdapter. When the swipe is completed, my adapter implementation fires a listener. The fragment's listener implementation tells the ViewModel which swipe action was done to which item. The ViewModel creates a new copy of the List with the relevant changes and publishes it back to the LiveData whose observer is calling `submitList()`. I don't recall seeing any issues like animations being duplicated. I can check my old code this weekend to see if I'm just remembering wrong.

Comment: But either way, this doesn't address the concern in the question about DiffUtil requiring new copies of the list for every change to item order or added/removed items. I haven't dealt with lists long enough that this would be a concern. If it is a concern, you might need a custom adapter and a custom List implementation that records changes to its contents to publish as `DiffUtil.DiffResults`. The custom adapter code could be adapted from the source code of ListAdapter but use this different way of getting DiffResults.

Comment: @Tenfour04 What I saw was that after a swipe, the items would go back to their original position briefly before `submitList` completed processing. It was more noticeable on a drag than a swipe. As far as requiring new copies of the list, the minimal object you could use in the posted list could just be an ID and a hash of the contents. You could then look up the things to display from the ViewModel using that ID in `onBindViewHolder`. But I can't think of very many cases where the list you post to a RecyclerView would have large objects in it to begin with to the point where that was needed.

Comment: The size of the objects doesn't matter since only their references get copied when doing a list copy. I was talking about the length of the list, which I think is what the OP was mentioning in the question. But I don't think it really is a concern. I can't imagine having a list long enough for the list copy to be of any significance in execution time, yet short enough to expect a user to be scrolling through it.

Comment: That's fair, I was thinking the list size concern was from building a new list (e.g. in the ViewModel, with potentially new objects) to re-submit to the ListAdapter. I think the answer to many of these concerns is to profile it first to see how much it actually matters...

Comment: @Tenfour04 Any luck reviewing your old code?  I just posted some additional code snippets that I tried...no luck with those either.

Comment: I just checked. It's as I described. My ListAdapter handles `submitList()` fine without messing up any animations from swiping items. I implemented swiping using `ItemTouchHelper` by following some tutorial on how to use it. I don't see any "hacks" in my code to avoid getting doubled animations when the list changes.

Comment: Does it work for drag/move operations too?

Comment: I've never tried implementing drag and move, so no.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I appreciate you checking your code.  The swiping feature I use is for deleting items and that part is working fine with ListAdapter...it's the drag and drop that I have not found a solution for.

Comment: @Tyler V In your code answer above, would setting up a single thread Executor to run your submitList() method be an easy way to run the Diff code on a background thread?

Comment: @AJW Setting up a thread in `submitList` would work to run the diff on the background thread, but you could have to be careful about the list being modified while the diff is still running (e.g. by a swipe or drag event that happens before the thread completes). Like we said above, profile it first and see how much it *actually* costs since it could introduce tricky to control behavior or bugs.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have posted a new question on ViewBinding and my ItemTouchHelper here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77903704/android-how-to-use-viewbinding-with-itemtouchhelper-swipe.  I would appreciate any insights or ideas you could offer on how to fix.